# Can't draw a commutative diagram

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I'm trying to draw a commutative diagram using `xymatrix`:

```
$\xymatrix{
S \ar@[ld]^{\pi_{i}} \ar@[rd]^{\pi_{j}}\\
R_{i} \ar[r]_{\mu_{ji}} & R_{j} }$
```

without any luck. Any idea?

EDIT: I'm trying to draw [the following commutative diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit):

[image]

Comment: How should the resulting diagram look like? Also, could using another package be an option?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Sorry I'm new hwere. It should an arrow (left diagonal) pointing to R_{i} and an arrow (right diagonal) pointing to R_{j} and between R_{i} and R_{j} a right arrow

Comment: Most commutative diagram packages work in a grid like this, so it's good to plan out your grid. In your code, there is no entry that is down-left from `S`. Also, in xymatrix the `@` is for changing the arrow style, e.g. for a dashed arrow one writes `\ar@{-->}`. [More examples here](http://www.jmilne.org/not/Mxymatrix.pdf). In our case no style was provided, so the arrow probably didn't draw.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's one possible solution for the lower part using both [`xy`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xy) and [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

$\xymatrix{
& S \ar[ld]^{\pi_{i}} \ar[rd]_{\pi_{j}} &\\
R_{i} \ar[rr]_{\mu_{ji}} & & R_{j} }$

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=normal]
& S \arrow{dl}{\pi_{i}}\arrow{dr}[swap]{\pi_{j}} & \\
R_{i} \arrow{rr}[swap]{\mu_{ji}} & & R_{j}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the complete diagram using `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=normal,row sep=large]
& Y\arrow{ddl}[swap]{\psi_{i}}\arrow{ddr}{\psi_{j}}\arrow{d}{h} & \\
& S \arrow{dl}{\pi_{i}}\arrow{dr}[swap]{\pi_{j}} & \\
R_{i} \arrow{rr}[swap]{\mu_{ji}} & & R_{j}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And now using `xy`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

$\xymatrix{
& Y\ar[ldd]_{\psi_{i}}\ar[rdd]^{\psi_{j}}\ar[d]^{h} & \\
& S \ar[ld]^{\pi_{i}} \ar[rd]_{\pi_{j}} & \\
R_{i} \ar[rr]_{\mu_{ji}} & & R_{j} }$

\end{document}
```

[image]

And now, as requested in a comment, with some arrows curved:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=normal,row sep=large]
& Y\arrow[bend right]{ddl}[swap]{\psi_{i}}\arrow[bend left]{ddr}{\psi_{j}}\arrow{d}{h} & \\
& S \arrow{dl}{\pi_{i}}\arrow{dr}[swap]{\pi_{j}} & \\
R_{i} \arrow{rr}[swap]{\mu_{ji}} & & R_{j}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with `xy`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

$\xymatrix{
& Y\ar@/_/[ldd]_{\psi_{i}}\ar@/^/[rdd]^{\psi_{j}}\ar[d]^{h} & \\
& S \ar[ld]^{\pi_{i}} \ar[rd]_{\pi_{j}} & \\
R_{i} \ar[rr]_{\mu_{ji}} & & R_{j} }$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user31509 for your first question, see my updated answer; for the second question, the package name is `tikz-cd`.

Comment: @user31509 give me some minutes and I'll post the code.

Comment: thanks, meanwhile a question: which package is better and why?

Comment: @user31509 First, a side note: don't forget (after a sensible wait) to accept my answer (or any other that might appear) if you consider that it solved your problem (in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954)). I updated my answer with the `xy` code. Personally I think that `tikz-cd` is more powerful since its built upon `PGF/TikZ`, but for simple diagrams, both are good.

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening: I downloaded tickz-cd.sty and copied to my latex,winedt and miktex folder, it still says "tikz-cd.sty" not found. In which folder should I install it?

Comment: @user31509 as a "quick solution", you can paste the file in the same folder containing your `.tex` file; be aware, however, that this package depends (at least) on `pgf/tikz` so you also need this package installed.

Comment: @user31509 the best thing to do is to use the MiKTeX package manager to install packages automatically.

Comment: thanks for being so helpful, the problem is that it does not appears there, don't know why.

Comment: @user31509 I also have no idea; the package is included in MiKTeX according to [its page in CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd). I don't use MiKTeX so I cannot give further advise on this respect, except that you should check you are using the more recent MiKTeX version.

Answer (score 5):

Here a solution with tkz-graph

```
  \documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
  \usepackage{tkz-graph}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,rotate=-30,->,>=latex,auto] 
  % vertices
     \SetVertexMath  % use math mode for vertex
     \GraphInit[vstyle=Empty] % Nodes are not drawn
     \Vertex{X} % add a vertex at (0,0)
     \Vertices{circle}{X_i,Y,X_j}   % three nodes on a circle
  %edges 

   \Edge[label=$\pi_j$](X)(X_j)   
   \Edge[label=$\Psi_i$,style={bend left}](Y)(X_i) 
   \Edge[label=$u$](Y)(X)  

  \begin{scope}[EdgeStyle/.append style={swap}] % swap labels
   \Edge[label=$\pi_i$](X)(X_i)  
   \Edge[label=$\Psi_j$,style={bend right}](Y)(X_j)
   \Edge[label=$f_{ij}$](X_j)(X_i)
  \end{scope}

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]