# How can I draw a 3-simplex diagram?

Tags: diagrams

[image]

But the direction of the arrows will be upward.(except for 1 ⟶ 0)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! I'd like to point you to [this article](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-3/tb120duck.pdf) for information on how to ask questions here. In particular, please show what sort of work you've done towards solving this problem.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57269/cant-draw-a-commutative-diagram?rq=1 should get you started.

Comment: May not be a duplicate. If this is just a commutative diagram then I agree with @Cragfelt but if OP wants a 3-simplex for (as an example) describing elementary homology calculations, then this is a different question.

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy with `tikz-cd`: to have upwards arrows, just use `u` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>=Stealth}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        & 3 \\[2.5ex]
        & 2 \ar[u] \\[1ex]
        1 \ar[rr] \ar[ru] \ar[ruu] && 0 \ar[lu] \ar[luu]   
    \end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to make a diagram that looks like a true 3-simplex.

[image]

Of course you can adjust colors, arrowheads, line thickness, opacity, etc. as you see fit. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round]

\coordinate [label=above:3] (3) at (0,{sqrt(2)},0);
\coordinate [label=left:2] (2) at ({-.5*sqrt(3)},0,-.5);
\coordinate [label=below:1] (1) at (0,0,1);
\coordinate [label=right:0] (0) at ({.5*sqrt(3)},0,-.5);

\begin{scope}[decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{to}}}]
\draw[densely dotted,postaction={decorate}] (0)--(2);
\draw[fill=lightgray,fill opacity=.5] (1)--(0)--(3)--cycle;
\draw[fill=gray,fill opacity=.5] (2)--(1)--(3)--cycle;
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (1)--(0);
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (1)--(2);
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (2)--(3);
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (1)--(3);
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (0)--(3);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`xy`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xypic) solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
    \xymatrix{
    & 3        \\
    & 2 \ar[u] \\
    1 \ar[rr] \ar[ru] \ar[ruu] && 0 \ar[lu] \ar[luu]
    }
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with plain TikZ. The outer triangle is equilateral.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[->]
    node (2) {2}
    +(0, 1) node (3) {3}
    +(-30:1) node (0) {0}
    +(210:1) node (1) {1}
    (1) edge (0)
    (0) edge (2)
    (0) edge (3)
    (1) edge (2)
    (1) edge (3)
    (2) edge (3)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With different arrow heads, for example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[->, >={Computer Modern Rightarrow[length=3pt, width=3pt]}]
    node (2) {2}
    +(0, 1) node (3) {3}
    +(-30:1) node (0) {0}
    +(210:1) node (1) {1}
    (1) edge (0)
    (0) edge (2)
    (0) edge (3)
    (1) edge (2)
    (1) edge (3)
    (2) edge (3)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]